# How to parse this HTML code with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I would like to parse this HTML code with BeautifulSoup.

Infact, for each job, I would like to obtain the time and the duration.
For example, I would like to obtain that:

> June 2012 – Present (3 years 2 months)

but I get that:

> July 2012

This my html code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<div id="background-experience" class="background-experience edit-default ">
<h3>Experience</h3>
<div id="experience-312465350" class="editable-item section-item current-position">
<div id="experience-312465350-view">
<header>
<h5 class="experience-logo" aria-hidden="true">
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/1288?trk=ppro_cprof">
<img class="lazy-load" src="https://static.licdn.com/scds/common/u/img/spacer.gif" data-li-src="https://media.licdn.com/media/p/5/005/00e/318/39cf760.png" alt="">
</a>
</h5>
<h4>
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/title/president-%26-ceo?trk=pprofile_title" title="Learn more about this title">President &amp; CEO</a>
</h4>
<h5>
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/1288?trk=ppro_cprof" dir="auto">Yahoo!</a>
</h5>
</header>
<span class="experience-date-locale">
<time>July 2012</time> – Present (3 years 1 month)<span class="locality">Sunnyvale, CA</span>
</span>
</div>
</div>
<div id="experience-297858215" class="editable-item section-item current-position">
<div id="experience-297858215-view">
<header>
<h5 class="experience-logo" aria-hidden="true">
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/2646?trk=ppro_cprof">
<img class="lazy-load" src="https://static.licdn.com/scds/common/u/img/spacer.gif" data-li-src="https://media.licdn.com/media/p/2/000/1d0/30a/07cd201.png" alt="">
</a>
</h5>
<h4>
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/title/board-of-directors?trk=pprofile_title" title="Learn more about this title">Board of Directors</a>
</h4>
<h5>
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/2646?trk=ppro_cprof" dir="auto">Walmart</a>
</h5>
</header>
<span class="experience-date-locale">
<time>June 2012</time> – Present (3 years 2 months)</span>
</div>
</div>
<script>$(function(){if(LI.Dialog){LI.Dialog().submitEvent.subscribe(function(type,args){var positionID;if(args[1]=='removePositionDialog'&&WebTracking&&WebTracking.trackUserAction){if(args[2]&&args[2].positionID){positionID=args[2].positionID;}WebTracking.trackUserAction('nprofile-edit-position-remove-submit',{positionID:positionID});}});}});</script>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc,'html.parser')
print soup.time.string
```

But when I try to obtain all the time, I've get just one.
How I can I resolve my problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using `.time`, since this will get you only the inner content of these elements - thus, the text `" – Present (3 years 2 months)"` is not contained.

Instead, search for the elements with the `experience-date-locale` class, which will be the `span`s that contain the whole text you want. Then, use `BeautifulSoup`'s `.text` to get only its text content (`<time>` and `</time>` won't be rendered).

For the sake of completeness, here's what my code (untested) would be:

```
spans = soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'experience-date-locale'})
for span in spans:
    print(span.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `<span>` to get your data. The approach for using the `<time>` will give you only the inner text but the one outside the `</time>` would not be printed as is your error.

For this we would simply use the `<span>` and the attribute `experience-date-locale`.

Use the following code snippet to parse your data:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
all_spans = soup.find_all('span', 'experience-date-locale')

parsed_content = []

for span in all_spans:
    parsed_content.append(span.text)
```